# Select only certain images with Python image webscraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a simple webscraper in python that find, download and create a pdf of certain images found in the website. For now I only created the webscraping part of the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

url = 'website url'
page = requests.get(url)
print('=== website ===\n',url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')

print('=== images found ===')

for img in images:
    if img.has_attr('src'):
        print(img['src'])
```

This is what I get:

```
=== website ===
 https://ita.net/stop-1/
=== images found ===
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/021-5.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/021-5-430x350.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/004-5-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/005-5-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/006-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/007-5-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/008-5-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/009-5-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/010-5-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/011-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/012-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/013-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/014-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/015-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/016-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/017-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/018-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/019-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/020-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/021-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/022-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/023-3-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/024-3-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/025-4-722x1024.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/ita-sidebar-5.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/telegram-1.jpg
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/ita-logo-w-1-1024x311.png
https://ita.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/premium-1024x407.png
```

I specified "certain" because my code finds all the images in the site and displays them. However I want only the images that ends in `722x1024.jpg` to be displayed (and so picked).
Someone has any idea on how to do it?

Comment: `if img['src'].endswith('722x1024.jpg'):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you can use `{'src': True}` to get images which have `src`.

Because `src` is a `string` so you can use any `string`-functions - ie. `.endswith()`

```
images = soup.find_all('img', {'src': True})

for img in images:
    if img['src'].endswith('722x1024.jpg'):
        print(img['src']))
```

`BeautifulSoup` allows also to use function in find:

```
def check(src):
    return (src is not None) and src.endswith('722x1024.jpg')

images = soup.find_all('img', {'src': check})

for img in images:
    print(img['src'])
```

or with `lambda`

```
images = soup.find_all('img', {'src': lambda x: (x is not None) and x.endswith('722x1024.jpg')})

for img in images:
    print(img['src'])
```

It may also use `regex`

```
import re

images = soup.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('722x1024.jpg$')})

for img in images:
    print(img['src'])
```

---

Minimal working example.

I search `0.jpg` on [books.toscrape.com](https://books.toscrape.com/) created (by authors of module [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)) specially to learn scraping.

(see also [toscrape.com](https://toscrape.com/))

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

print('--- version 1 ---')

images = soup.find_all('img', {'src': True})

for img in images:
    if img['src'].endswith('0.jpg'):
        print(img['src'])

print('--- version 2 a ---')

def check(src):
    return (src is not None) and src.endswith('0.jpg')

images = soup.find_all('img', {'src': check})

for img in images:
    print(img['src'])

print('--- version 2 b ---')

images = soup.find_all('img', {'src': lambda x: (x is not None) and x.endswith('0.jpg')})

for img in images:
    print(img['src'])
    
print('--- version 3 ---')

import re

images = soup.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('0.jpg$')})

for img in images:
    print(img['src'])
```

Results:

```
--- version 1 ---
media/cache/3e/ef/3eef99c9d9adef34639f510662022830.jpg
media/cache/be/f4/bef44da28c98f905a3ebec0b87be8530.jpg
--- version 2 a ---
media/cache/3e/ef/3eef99c9d9adef34639f510662022830.jpg
media/cache/be/f4/bef44da28c98f905a3ebec0b87be8530.jpg
--- version 2 b ---
media/cache/3e/ef/3eef99c9d9adef34639f510662022830.jpg
media/cache/be/f4/bef44da28c98f905a3ebec0b87be8530.jpg
--- version 3 ---
media/cache/3e/ef/3eef99c9d9adef34639f510662022830.jpg
media/cache/be/f4/bef44da28c98f905a3ebec0b87be8530.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
imgs = []
for img in images:
    
    if img.has_attr('src'):
        if "722x1024.jpg" in img['src']:
           imgs.append(img['src'])
```

Or:

```
img_list = soup.find_all(
            lambda tag:tag.name == 'img' and
            'src' in tag.attrs and '722x1024.jpg' in tag.attrs['src'])
```